# How can we reuse JSP chunk defined within JSP Page; without creating another JSP file?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have 14 piece of code at different places in JSP which is getting repeated at 14 places in JSP:

```
<div>
 <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="economy"/></td>
            <td>${spm}</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <td><spring:message code="nok"/></td>
            <td>${spm.nok}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Requirement to define above chunk at one place and reuse 14 times.

I know i can create its .JSPF and include it again using <% include.

But we want to avoid this as i have to apply same for other chunks too and i am told not to make much files.

So is there any way to define JSP chunk inside page(somewhere in header or footer or in HTML element) and reuse at multiple places on load? Please ask if anything unclear in question

**Update**:
Please also consider following while answering:

```
<c:forEach varStatus="loop" items="${economy}" var="spm"> 
  //Code Chunk spm.nok
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach varStatus="loop" items="${economy1}" var="spm"> 
 //Code Chunk spm.nok
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: You can use custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this data on index page with display none and whenever you want copy that div and paste using jQuery or javasscript.

Comment: Thanks. But what if snippet used inside FOR each of JSP on multiple objects BUT code inside it is same:

<c:forEach varStatus="loop" items="${economy}" var="spm">
Code Chunk
</c:forEach>

Comment: write a javascript function that contain your dynamic table data every time pass only object to that method that will return whole div content and paste it wherever you want.

Comment: Updated the scenario in question. If i write data in div display none. Then the object within that will not be updated as expected. JSP loads first and will not able to detect what object it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is pretty typical but interesting, ideal way is to make a JSP/JSPF with re-usable code and include it, like you have said.

I would recommend discuss with your folks and consider using [JSP Templates](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076174/java-web-development/jsp-templates.html) or some other templating mechanism, but considering your requirement, I think your best bet can be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script lang="javascript">
        var reusableHtml = "<div>  <table border='1'>    <tbody>        <tr>            <td>0</td>            <td>${spm}</td>       </tr>       <tr>            <td>A</td>            <td>B</td>       </tr>    </tbody> </table></div>";

        function pushReusbalecode(){
            alert('1');
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = reusableHtml;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = reusableHtml;
        }

    </script> 
</head>
<body onload="pushReusbalecode()">

<div id="demo1"></div>

<br>##########################<br>

<div id="demo2"></div>

<br>##########################<br>

</body>        



</html>
```

Comment: Give you give a try? Does it answer your question? I think given your requirement and not using any templating solution, this could be best bet.